# Euler-Lagrange for Anharmonic Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation

> **Suppose we are given some potential: $V(x)=\frac{1}{2}kx^2+\frac{1}{4}\lambda x^4$ where $k$ and $\lambda$
>   are constants.**

$\\$
i) I'm trying to find the Lagrangian and use Euler-Lagrange to find the Equation of Motion.

So i know the Lagrangian is $$L=T-V$$ which leads to my guess: $$\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2-(\frac{1}{2}kx^2+\frac{1}{4}\lambda x^4)$$ giving us $$\frac{d}{dt}(m\dot x)-(kx+\lambda x^3)=0$$ and hence $$m\ddot x-kx-\lambda x^3=0$$ and now I'm stuck from this point on, and unsure what to do here.

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform (Mathematica) spits out an answer readily enough, but the solutions are complicated and use the Jacobi elliptic function. Not an easy DE you've got there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sign is wrong. You should get $m\ddot x+\nabla V(x)=0$ from the Euler-Lagrange equation $0=-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{∂L}{∂\dot x}+\frac{∂L}{∂x}$.

---

As $H=T+V$ is a first integral, you get
$$
\frac{m}{k}\dot x^2+x^2+\fracλ{2k}x^4=R^2=const.
$$
which motivates to set $$\dot x=R\omega\cos(ωu),~~~ y=g(x)=x\sqrt{1+\fracλ{2k}x^2}=R\sin(ωu),$$ $ω^2=\frac{k}m$. Now $g$ is smooth and monotonically increasing, so the inverse function $f=g^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable. With $x=f(R\sin(ωu))$ leading to a second form for $$\dot x=f'(R\sin(ωu))ωR\cos(ωu)\dot u$$ we get
$$
\dot u=\frac1{f'(R\sin(ωu))}
$$
which reduces the problem to a simple scalar ODE for the angular factor $u$ with a positive right side.

Comment: A bit unsure why we are using the Hamiltonian equation? - I did end up getting the desired result of $m\ddot x +kx+\lambda x^3=0$ , to get the solutions would I use the auxiliary equation method?

Comment: Because the Hamiltonian is a first integral and can thus be used to reduce the order of the equation. I'm not sure what the "auxiliary equation method" is, but in general, if a non-linear ODE does not have an obvious solution (or one that WA finds), then it is almost certain that no symbolic solution exists.

Comment: Oh right, that makes a bit more sense. Can you also explain why you have divided by k and multiplied by a factor of 2. And where $R^2$ comes from?

Comment: $R^2$ is the constant that comes from the constant energy. The coefficients were manipulated to be close to a circle equation for where $x=R\sin\phi+O(R^2)$. Other variants to reduce the number of parameters are possible, you could bring the equation to the form $\dot x^2+ω^2x^2(1+2\gamma x^2)=r^2$, closer to some harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is the correct method, since the next question is to figure out the Equation of Motion using the Hamiltons Equation which would be the answer above right?

Comment: For the "real" Hamiltonian you get $H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(q)$ so that $\dot q=H_p=p/m$ and $\dot p = -H_q=-\nabla V(q)$. Which is all of course compatible with all the other formulations.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobi elliptic function $\text{sn}(x,c)$ (in Maple's parametrization: note that in Mathematica this would be JacobiSN[x, c^2]) satisfies 
$$ \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \text{sn}(x,c) = (-c^2-1) \text{sn}(x,c) + 2 c^2 \text{sn}(x,c)^3 $$

For appropriate choices of $a$, $b$ and $c$, $a\; \text{sn}(b (t - t_0), c)$ will satisfy your equation.